# Body or Message Contains method using MailKit

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I'm using MailKit for received messages via Imap.

Now I need a search-logic for the software and I got a some troubles.

For ex, I using:

```
var query = SearchQuery.BodyContains("SomeTextfromEmail");
( or var query = SearchQuery.MessageContains("SomeTextfromEmail"); )

foreach (UniqueId uid in imapfolder.Search(query)){
  //some logic
}
```

So, I can't get messages with text contains on it with Search filter.
I'm downloaded message ( message.WriteTo(string.Format(@"C:{0}.eml", uid)); )
and see the message content. Text of message in a base-64 format.

How do it correctly? I need decode message text from base64?

Problem are here:

```
var query = SearchQuery.BodyContains("Iphone").And(SearchQuery.All);  //this construction find messages in folder
foreach (var uid in imapfolder.Search(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.From + "  :  " + uid.ToString());
}


var query = SearchQuery.BodyContains("Received from Iphone").And(SearchQuery.All); //this construction can't find message in folder
foreach (var uid in imapfolder.Search(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.From + "  :  " + uid.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If the message is base 64 encoded then yes it seems you would have to decode it.

Comment: Yes, but how?

I need search messages by the filter not by decode body - find text - next message.
I want get array of message uids by the search method.

Comment: ImpFolder.Search() already returns a list of message uids. Your comment makes your question even more confusing than it already was.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a jumbled mess of confusion (your question starts out saying you are trying to figure out how to search and then you end with asking how to base64 decode the raw message that you saved to a file) so I have no idea exactly what you want to know.

If all you want is the decoded text body, you can do this:

```
var message = imapfolder.GetMessage (uid);
var text = message.TextBody;
```

This will be the decoded text string (either base64 decoded or quoted-printable decoded if it needs to be).

The MimeKit [README](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/README.md) and [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md) are both full of useful information on the basics of how to use them. I would highly recommend reading them as they may be helpful.

Update:

Based on the comment added to my answer, it *sounds like* what you want to do is this?

```
var matched = new UniqueIdSet ();
foreach (var uid in folder.Search (SearchQuery.BodyContains ("iPhone"))) {
    var message = folder.GetMessage (uid);
    var body = message.TextBody;

    if (body != null && body.Contains ("Received from iPhone"))
        matched.Add (uid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

For ex. i have message with text - "Received from Iphone".
I wan't take this message by mailkit Search.

var query = SearchQuery.BodyContains("Iphone"); - matched the message
var query = SearchQuery.BodyContains("Received from Iphone"); - not matched the message

So, it's job like a keyword? I can't use Contains method like this .BodyContains("Received from Iphone") and i need to use BodyContains("Iphone"); like this?

Comment: See my updated answer. Your question is still very confusingly worded but I *think* I might have figured out what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Sorry, my English is very bad.

I want get uids of messages where message contains this text - "Received from iPhone". 
(I have messages with this text)

I can't get uids if i search text "Received from iPhone" but i can get uids when i use for search text "iPhone". So, I cant use whole text in message for search uids and i need to use a part of text (for e.x. Iphone)?

Comment: I think it would help if you explained what the difference is that you are getting with your 2 code snippets. You keep providing us with incomplete information, forcing us to GUESS what you are trying to say. It’s like if I typed the first half of a sentence and expected you to figure out the rest.

Comment: For Example:

(Message)
Hi!
How are you?
----
Received from iPhone


I want get uid of this message.
I trying to get uid by MessageContains and BodyContains methods.


If I search for the full sentence from the text (ex. .BodyContains("How are you?") or .BodyContains("Received from iPhone")) I can't find this message and uid.

But, if i search by sentence word (ex. .BodyContains("iPhone") or .BodyContains("Received")) i get this message uid.

Why?

Comment: Trouble on this and only this?

Comment: Try getting a log of the IMAP commands to see for yourself: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog

Comment: Thank u, now i want try send imap commands from telnet to test it

Comment: Good idea. Search ietf.org for etc 3501 for the IMAP protocol docs.

Comment: Did you figure it out? What was the issue?